# Fill array with value and null binary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array and max count for something. I want to create new array like this with the above information.

Input:

```js
const maxCount = 8;
const anArray = ["P1", "P2", "P3"];
```

Wanted result:

```js
// Length is maxCount
0 = "P1" // anArray[0]
1 = null

2 = "P2" // anArray[1]
3 = null

4 = "P3" // anArray[2]
5 = null

6 = null // anArray[3] is undefined, null then
7 = null
```

Fill index if available, fill null next one. Results are group of two. Fill empty values null until reach the maxCount.

If the input:

```js
const maxCount = 8;
const anArray = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"];
```

Result will be:

```js
// Length is maxCount
0 = "P1" // anArray[0]
1 = "P5" // anArray[4]

2 = "P2" // anArray[1]
3 = null

4 = "P3" // anArray[2]
5 = null

6 = "P4" // anArray[3]
7 = null
```

This result is OK too:

```js
// Length is maxCount
0 = "P1" // anArray[0]
1 = "P2" // anArray[1]

2 = "P3" // anArray[2]
3 = null

4 = "P4" // anArray[3]
5 = null

6 = "P5" // anArray[4]
7 = null
```

Every group of two must has an anArray item.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Already added. "Result:". Changed to title "Wanted result:"

Comment: @gereksizler yeah but that doesnt look like a data structure, can you create a required data structure you need?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I have only maxCount and anArray. I want to create new array maxCount length.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const maxCount = 8;
const anArray = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10"];

let result = [];
let arrLen = anArray.length;

for(let i=0; i < arrLen; i++) {
  if(i == maxCount) {     // if anArray.length >= maxCount stop for loop
      break;
  }

  if(i*2 >= maxCount) {   // if anArray.length >= maxCount/2 start over + 1
    result[i*2 - maxCount + 1] = anArray[i];
  } else {
    result.push(anArray[i]);
    result.push(null);
  }
}

// if anArray.length < maxCount/2 then fill with nulls
for(let i=arrLen*2; i < maxCount; i++) {
   result.push(null);
}

console.log(result);
```

It may be best to put the code in a function so you can reuse it easily:

```js
function fillArray(anArray) {
  const maxCount = 8;
  let arrLen = anArray.length;
  let result = [];

  for(let i=0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    if(i == maxCount) {     // if anArray.length >= maxCount stop for loop
        break;
    }

    if(i*2 >= maxCount) {   // if anArray.length >= maxCount/2 start over + 1
      result[i*2 - maxCount + 1] = anArray[i];
    } else {
      result.push(anArray[i]);
      result.push(null);
    }
  }

  // if anArray.length < maxCount/2 then fill with nulls
  for(let i=arrLen*2; i < maxCount; i++) {
     result.push(null);
  }
  
  return result;
}

const anArray1 = ["P1", "P2", "P3"];
const anArray2 = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6"];
const anArray3 = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10"];

console.log( fillArray(anArray1) );
console.log( fillArray(anArray2) );
console.log( fillArray(anArray3) );
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This is works perfect for create the first example but not works on other result that I want to get.

Comment: @gereksizler yeah, I just saw your second edit a few minutes ago. I'll edit to include a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for adding later. I should have given more details first.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I'm trying to solve this problem. I think I'm solved.

```js
const playerCount = 8;
const players = [
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P3",
    "P4",
    "P5"
];

const result = [];

let p = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < playerCount / 2; i++) {
    result[i] = [];

    result[i][0] = players[p];
    p++;
}

for(let i = 0; i < playerCount / 2; i++) {
    result[i][1] = players[p] !== undefined ? players[p] : null;
    p++;
}

console.log(...[].concat(...result));
```

Comment: When `anArray.length < maxCount/2` one of the values becomes `undefined` instead of null.